# How to align input with a checkbox (pull-right) in the same row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a text input and a checkbox in the same row and col. If I add pull-right class to the checkbox, how can I fill remaing space on the left with the text input? I'm using Bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="checkbox i-checks pull-right">
                <label> <input type="checkbox" >
                    <i></i> Fixed width label
                </label>
</div>

<input class="form-control">
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tsnwLx5o/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/snlacks/togpvwwk/

This is built into Bootstrap CSS. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios

Use an input-group, and use an input-group-addon. Put it before or after the input, inside the input-groupd.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <label for="input_name">My field</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="input_name" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="Text on left, check over there ==>"> 
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Over here on the right">
                        Title Label
                    </label>
                </span>
            </div>
            <!-- /input-group -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this. Is there an easy way to remove that gray background and border (for single case, not globally)? Also, how can I improve vertical alignment / lower the checkbox?

Comment: I tried adding margin-top to the label, but it increases height of the addon then.

Comment: Yes. You can add a .input-group-addon.white-background, .input-group-addon.white-background label { background: white; } and add the white_background class to the input-group-addon span.

Comment: If you add the height to the input-group and the text input, it will be taller.
            <div class="input-group" style="height: 60px">
                <input type="text" style="height: 60px"